# Conditionally rendering the same component does not trigger mounted() hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-statements, rendering

I'm pretty new to Vue so please correct me if my thinking process is wrong. I'm trying to conditionally render a component like this:

```
<div>
  <Map v-if="bool" mapSrc="src1.jpg" :idList="idList1" :data="dataVariable1"></Map>
  <Map v-else mapSrc="src2.jpg" :idList="idList2" :data="dataVariable2"></Map>
</div>
```

My goal here is to render the same component with different props depending on the v-if state. So when bool is true it should render the first component, and when i toggle bool to be false, it should render the second option. The props seems to be changing correctly, but when i toggle the bool state it does not seem to run the mounted() hook again, which is an indication that component1 does not seem to dismount, it just switches out the props basically.

What I want is that when bool is false, it should render a fresh version of that whole component instance, and be isolated of what previously was going on in component 1.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to use `v-show`? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-show

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but v-show is not what I want. 

"The difference is that an element with v-show will always be rendered and remain in the DOM; v-show only toggles the display CSS property of the element."

I want only component 1 or component 2 to exist in the DOM depending on the bool state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to Linus Borg's answer [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/for-2-same-components-with-v-if-and-v-else-mounted-hook-is-only-called-once/10246/3), You should add a unique `key` attribute to both of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can a achieve this by using `key` attribute
Specify different `key` for the 2 Map components.

```
<Map v-if="bool" mapSrc="src1.jpg" :idList="idList1" :data="dataVariable1" key="map1"></Map>
  <Map v-else mapSrc="src2.jpg" :idList="idList2" :data="dataVariable2" key="map2"></Map>
```